# Formato de data padrão brasil não funciona no bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho esse componente datepicker do bootstrap

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <input id="dataSolicitacao" type="text" name="timepicker" class="b-datepicker form-control form-white" placeholder="Informe a data" data-orientation="top">
</div>
```

Coloquei esses javascripts

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR",
        minViewMode: 0;
        orientation: auto
    });
  });
</script>
```

Ou esse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#dataSolicitacao').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });
  });
</script>
```

O fato é que nenhum deles funcionou. Esse último, pior, pois ele abre outro calendário por baixo com opção de hora, e ele não fecha ao escolher a data e clicar fora. Sem também não fecha ao escolher a data, mas ao clicar fora do calendário, fecha.

Como altero o formato de data para o português Brasil(dd/MM/yyyy)?

Comment: pq não utilizar o Datepicker do JQuery UI?  https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ . Lá existe uma option que define a região da data.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando o formato errado. Segundo a [documentação do Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate):

> dd - day of month (two digit)
>
> [...]
>
> DD - day name
>
> [...]
>
> mm - month of year (two digit)
>
> [...]
>
> MM - month name long

Portanto, você deveria estar usando

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR",
        minViewMode: 0;
        orientation: auto
    });
  });
```

Comment: Pablo, essa abordagem eu já tentei e não funciona. A data continua no padrão EUA.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar esse sem alterar nada, caso atenda suas necessidades, você vai adaptando no seu uso.

```
<div class="well">
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
<input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
<span class="add-on">
  <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
});
</script>
```

Caso queira saber mais tem [esse link na github explicando o Datapicker](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: Victor, esse seu componente altera o layout da aplicação. Teria que ser o DatePicker do bootstrap mesmo.

Comment: Mas ele é do bootstrap @pnet

Comment: consulte https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Então, mas ele quebrou meu layout. Ficou diferente o formato do campo. Mas, vou consultar sim.

Comment: @pnet use apenas o JS e a classe data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"

Comment: Cara, preciso ler mais sobre o bootstrap. Fiz da forma acima e comparei com o que foi postado no git por você, VictorGomes. Na minha página não funcionou. Talvez algum include esteja matando, só pode ser. Sempre que coloco `language: 'pt-BR'` no js do calendário, aparece um botão Done e o calendário não fecha por nada, após a seleção da data e ele cobre o elemento não dando para ver como ficou o formato e não fecha mesmo, mesmo clicando fora do calendário, apertando `Done` e etc.

Comment: olhe pela versão do bootstrap que você usa, algumas versões mais novas sobrepõe algumas classes das versões antigas. Em relação ao ler mais sobre bootstrap, eu apoio com toda a certeza, conhecimento nunca é demais.

Answer (score 0):

fiz um ajuste no seu código, acredito que agora está funcionando a caixa de data, como vc não mencionou utilizei a ultima versão estável dos **frameworks**

não simulei para o `datetimepicker()`, pq acredito que agora deva rodar só com **datepicker()**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* treixo do seu código 
  $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR",
    minViewMode: 0;
    orientation: auto
  });
  
  Observe que o variável 'minViewMode' termina com ';' isso quebra a leitura do JS e
  a variável 'orientation' é uma string então precisa das aspas, ex. 'auto'
  
  */
  
  $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy", // modifique para o formato que deseja, utilizei o seu formato colado no ex.
    language: "pt-BR"
    // removi o minViewMode: 0; pq o valor 0 é o padrão
    // removi o orientation: auto, pq o valor 'auto' é o padrão
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- treixo do seu código -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input id="dataSolicitacao" type="text" name="timepicker" class="b-datepicker form-control form-white" placeholder="Informe a data" data-orientation="top">
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom, mas para facilitar a usabilidade teria como o datepicker fechar quando escolhesse uma data?